# How to print out a list of all files in a Visual Studio solution

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to cleanup some code for a web API. I think about half of the files (mostly classes) aren't even used. Is there any why I can print out a list of all the files so that I can check them off as I see fit? I should probably mention that many of the files are contained within folders so something that would also open all those folders is necessary. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Open a command prompt to your solution's (or project's) root folder. Type `tree`. Redirect to a file, if you like, so you can print it out.

Comment: Thanks works perfectly